# Acess Gridview on Hubsection's datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

How can I access "grid_my" on the data template of the "hub_my"?

```
<HubSection x:Name="hub_my" DataContext="{Binding my}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView
                    x:Name="grid_my"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged"
                    Loaded="grid_Loaded">
                 </GridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
{
    int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
    for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
        FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
        // Not a framework element or is null
        if (fe == null) return null;

        if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
        {
            // Found the control so return
            return child;
        }
        else
        {
            // Not found it - search children
            DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
            if (nextLevel != null)
                return nextLevel;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then you can get your GridView like this :

```
GridView myGrid = FindChildControl<GridView>(hub_my, "grid_my") as GridView;
```